# How do you add a Star Rating to the Alert component in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native, alert, rating

I am trying to get add a Star Rating Component into an Alert using "AirbnbRating" from "react-native-ratings" and "Alerts" "react-native" but am having trouble integrating the two together. They work fine independently, but have not figured out how to add anything other than text to the alert feature.

It may be worth noting that I am using the "function" format instead of "class" format.

Can anyone offer some insight? Thank you in advanced!

Edit:

```
const checkComplete = () => {

  if (!complete.trim()){

      return;
  }

  Alert.alert(

    "Checking hunger.",

    "Are you hungry?",

    [

      {

        text: "Yes",

        onPress: () => Alert.alert(

           'Express hunger',

           'Please express your hunger',

           [        

              {

                 text: 'Okay',

                 onPress: () => navigation.navigate('RateHunger')

              },
  
           ]
   

        ),

     },

     {

        text: "No",

     }]

  )

}

onPress: { checkComplete }
```

Comment: Alert is used to display texts, are you trying to make a popup which has a ratings input ?

Comment: Yes, this sounds like what I am trying to do

Comment: You can use the Modal for that and have the rating inside that

Comment: Can you share what you have tried with the rating component, so that i can update it with a modal ?

Comment: Am I able to go from an alert to a modal? I currently have an alert that asks the user a question that then takes them to another alert where I wanted the star rating to be. Can I go from an alert to a modal?

Comment: yeah you can control the visibility of the modal so you can do this

Comment: How would I go about adding it to this? I added it to the original post.

Comment: you mean added it to this question ? i dont see any update

Comment: Yes, my apologizes

Comment: Check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Modal to make a custom component like below

```
function RatingAlert({ visible, callback }) {
  return (
    <Modal
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}
      visible={visible}
      onRequestClose={() => {
        if (callback) callback();
      }}>
      <Rating
        showRating
        onFinishRating={this.ratingCompleted}
        style={{ paddingVertical: 10 }}
      />
      <Button title="Ok" onPress={callback} />
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

And use it like below
//const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

```
 <RatingAlert
      visible={visible}
      callback={() => {
        //Your custom call for OK button
        setVisible(false);
      }}
    />
```

And whenever you want to show it you can simply

```
setVisible(true)
```

This is a basic version and you can extend it by sending more props and customize it.

Comment: I was trying to add the modal to an existing alert function, Your code worked, but just not quite what I was looking for

Comment: you cant do that but this will work similar to the alert as a popup, you can style according to your need

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your time

Comment: You are welcome, please do mark the answer if it fixes your issue :)

Comment: It didn't quite do what I was looking for, but it helped me decide that I need to take another avenue; helpful nonetheless.